# How to implement search and filter function using useSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

I've tried implementing a search function but it does not seem to be working. I am new to `searchParams` and have no idea if I am doing it right.

The app will show the whole list of data upon loading.

My data looks like this  [{"PROFILE_NUMBER": "A123", "NAME": "X", "AGE" : "21", "HOBBY" : "RUN"} , .....]

In the first block of code (Card.js), the input bar will take in the input (e.g. the profile number) from the user. The return will filter what the user has typed and map out the results (list of profiles tied to the number). Then the user is able to click on the result and navigate to the Single.js code.

The code will then map out the code in the second block (individual profile).

This is the Card.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Link, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Card = ({ profiles }) => {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={searchParams.get("filter") || ""}
        onChange={(event) => {
          let filter = event.target.value;
          if (filter) {
            setSearchParams({ filter });
          } else {
            setSearchParams({});
          }
        }}
      />
      {profiles
        .filter((profile) => {
          let filter = searchParams.get("filter");
          if (!filter) return true;
          let profile = profile.PROFILE_NUMBER;
          return profile.filter;
        })
        .map((profile) => (
          <div className="container">
            <Link
              style={{ display: "block", margin: "1rem 0" }}
              to={`/profiles/${profile.PROFILE_NUMBER}`}
              key={profile.PROFILE_NUMBER}
            >
              <div>
                {profile.PROFILE_NUMBER}
                <br />
                {profile.NAME}
                <br />
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Here is the Single.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

const Single = ({ profiles }) => {
  const { profileIndex } = useParams();

  const profile = profiles[profileIndex];

  if (!profile) {
    return "No Profile";
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {`Report Number: ${profile.PROFILE_NUMBER}`}
      <br />
      {`County: ${profile.NAME}`}
      <br />
      {`Year: ${profile.AGE}`}
      <br />
      {`Description: ${profile.HOBBY}`}
    </div>
  );
};
```

For now, the code will accept an input but it will not filter the list and generate the result for me. How do I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data structure you described, these lines in the filter statement are likely the problem:

```
let profile = profile.PROFILE_NUMBER; // "A123"
return profile.filter;
```

There's no `filter` property in a string literal, the result is undefined and the filtered profile is thus empty. Maybe you're referring to `return profile == filter` there?

Comment: I referred to the documentation on searchParams and was not sure what this line of code does.  
     
        .filter((profile) => {
          let filter = searchParams.get("filter");
          if (!filter) return true;